# Trying to understand the behavior of the bond market during the COVID19 crisis

Tags: bonds, debt, markets, government-bonds, corporate-bonds

I'm aware of several corporate bond indices that are (slightly) going up despite of the COVID19 crisis. For instance, let's take [this corporate bond index](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/LFGATRUU:IND) as an example.

Choosing the 1Y chart one can perfectly the COVID19 fall down, however, from that particular moment until now, it has raised a bit.

My understanding is that, after the COVID19 fall, central banks have lowered the interest rates a lot, therefore 'the bonds from yesterday should be much worthy than those of today and tomorrow' Isn't this correct?

How is it possible that corporate bonds raise (even if it is only a bit) under the present circumstances, with central banks printing money and downgrading interest rates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemed to have partly answered your own question:

When interest rates go down, the prices of existing fixed-rate bond rise, since if you were to replace those bonds you'd either get a lower interest rate or have to pay a premium. So if interest rates go down it's not surprising that bond prices (and thus bond funds) go up.

With corporate bonds, there is also a credit risk component, so if corporate bond funds go up in value it either means that spreads have gone down (which means less risk of default and thus higher bond prices) or that the gain due to interest rate declines overshadows the loss due to credit spreads widening.

Comment: @DStankey but if you see the index chart above, you will find that bonds start rising much after the COVID19 fall down. Therefore, the interest rates were already very low when the bonds started to go up again. One might think that they (interest rates) went even lower, but that can't be since they are already almost 0.

Comment: Then corporate spreads must have narrowed (less risk of default) to raise the bond prices. Which could have happened if spreads widened greatly in the early days out of panic, and then narrowed as things settled.